# Retrieve data without html tag in Laravel

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, ckeditor

Content in my database: `<h2> This is heading text</h2>`

I want to retrieve this without **html** **tags** but with bold format as `<h2>` tag does .

In this case: `strip_tags()` only removes the tags.

Comment: How to you expect text to be bold without a tag making it bold?

Comment: There are plenty of possible solutions for this problem, but you need to provide more information so people can help you -- what other html codes might come out of your database? Where are you displaying the text, and what tools are available to you there to adjust font weight?

Comment: "bold format" is simply a result of CSS.  If you want your content to have a specific CSS applied, it must be within _some_ container that you can target with the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default once you do {{ $foo->bar }} laravel retrieves everything as plain text. You may be looking at retrieving it this way instead. {!! $foo->bar !!}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using **blade** template :

```
{!! $data->content !!}
```

Using above code remove all **HTML** tags .

If you want to retrieve **HTML** code to page you can use the below code :

```
{!! html_entity_decode($data->content) !!}
```

If you want to get *Text Plan* only without **HTML** code use the below code :

```
{{htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($data->content)))}}
```

For more details : [Displaying Data - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)